# Product languages

Tags: symfony1

I am new to Symfony but I need to debug a retail  application that displays in real time the sales from all the stores
Sales from the stores are recorded in a database.

Schema of the database is provided hereafter
The user complains when displaying all stores (MAGASINS in French) the result is sorted with the following arguments : COD_TYPE first that the users do not want , then come COD_MAGASIN and other arguments that meet the user requirements

As we are using the Symfony Framework to handle all the interractions between the web service and the database, where shall I look to be able to change the display sequence?

Regards
Jean Bruma

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

## -- CIMAGASIN

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CIMAGASIN`;   
        
CREATE TABLE `CIMAGASIN`        
(       
    `COD_MAGASIN` VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL,    
    `COD_DELEGUE` VARCHAR(5),   
    `COD_PAYS` VARCHAR(5),  
    `COD_REGION` VARCHAR(5),    
    `COD_DEPARTEMENT` VARCHAR(5),   
    `COD_EMPLACEMENT` VARCHAR(5),   
    `COD_TYPE` VARCHAR(5),  
    `COD_CONCEPT` VARCHAR(5),   
    `LIB_MAGASIN` VARCHAR(35),  
    `SF_MAGASIN` INTEGER,   
    `LIB_TYPE_D_ETABLISSEMENT` VARCHAR(35), 
    `DATE_OUVERTURE` DATE,  
    `DATE_FERMETURE` DATE,  
    `TARIF_MAG` VARCHAR(10),    
    `CP` VARCHAR(10),   
    `LIB_VILLE` VARCHAR(35),    
    `ADRESSE` VARCHAR(100), 
    `COD_TRANSPORTEUR` VARCHAR(10), 
    `COD_ETABLISSEMENT` VARCHAR(10),    
    `COD_DEVISE` VARCHAR(5),    
    `STATUT` INTEGER,   
    `COD_CAPACITE` VARCHAR(5),  
    `COMPARABLE` VARCHAR(1),    
    `COMPARABLE_ANTER` VARCHAR(1),  
    `ZONE_COM` VARCHAR(35), 
    PRIMARY KEY (`COD_MAGASIN`),    
    INDEX `CIMAGASIN_FI_1` (`COD_REGION`),  
    CONSTRAINT `CIMAGASIN_FK_1` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`COD_REGION`)
        REFERENCES `CIREGION` (`COD_REGION`),
    INDEX `CIMAGASIN_FI_2` (`COD_TYPE`),    
    CONSTRAINT `CIMAGASIN_FK_2` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`COD_TYPE`)
        REFERENCES `CITYPE` (`COD_TYPE`),
    INDEX `CIMAGASIN_FI_3` (`COD_CONCEPT`), 
    CONSTRAINT `CIMAGASIN_FK_3` 
        FOREIGN KEY (`COD_CONCEPT`)
        REFERENCES `CICONCEPT_MAG` (`COD_CONCEPT`)
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you need. I think you want to change the sort order of a list but get confused with the 'Product languages'  title...

Comment: If this is a problem with the sorting of the list, we need the PHP code that builds the list. The sorting can be done in the action in the controller, or in a specialized method in the Store table.

Answer (score 0):

Start with your controller and see which views/models are being called.

I'm guessing that there is a "Store_sales" model being called that is `SELECT`-ing `COD_type` as part of the `result()` for the "store_sales" view.